Нужно ли выделять запятыми "тем более" в данном предложении?
Нужно ли выделять запятыми "тем более" в данном предложении? В пятницу желательно не планировать важных и (,) тем более (,) рискованных дел.

А союз и здесь необходим?

Обособление допускается для смыслового выделения.:
(1) В пятницу желательно не планировать важных и тем более  рискованных дел.
(2) В пятницу желательно не планировать важных и, тем более,  рискованных дел.
Справочник

Частица. То же, что «особенно». Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Они уже не казались такими наглыми или тем более страшными, как несколько часов назад. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Град обреченный.

В художественной литературе встречаются примеры употребления слов «тем более» в роли вводных:  Мне, тем более, домой скоро. В. Короленко, Чудная.

